# SSDT-BI SQL Version Compatability

Tags: sql-server, ssdt, ssdt-bi

I'm working on upgrading some SSIS packages from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2012 and am getting somewhat confused by the SSDT-BI tools.

I have downloaded "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013" from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=42313), which according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx) supports "SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2".

When upgrading a package I don't see an option to upgrade "up to 2012" only. In other words, how can I stop the packages being upgraded too far? Or are 2012/14 pretty much cross compatible?

Also, are there other similar implications for SSRS, SSAS solutions?

If I need a different version to ONLY upgrade to 2012, which would I need?

Comment: Are you running into errors when trying to deploy to a 2012 server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stop using VS2013 for SSIS 2012. It [builds SSIS 2014 packages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2014/04/02/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2013-ssdt-bi/) that can't be deployed to SSIS 2012. Instead install [SSDT-BI for VS2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843).

Another option is installing [SSDT preview for VS2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx). It is a currently a release candidate for SQL 2016 but is able to support downlevel versions back to SSIS 2012. So the story will be much less confusing soon (or now if you are willing to use beta software).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Does the SSDT for VS2015 allow you to select a target version for for RS/AS/IS?

Comment: @John yes, exactly